# JOGL Jar runs fine on my development machine, but slowly on others? Even if they have better hardware

Tags: java, performance, executable-jar, jogl, bulletphysics

I am currently messing around with JOGL and JBullet with some success. I'd like to share what I've created with my friends. I created a jar file and a .bat to open it with the argument -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true. The jar runs perfectly on my machine. It opens and runs on my friends system and my laptop, but at an **extremely** low frame rate. What is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Also for some reason it loads the wrong textures for some objects, again only when ran on another system. They are both Windows 8.1 x64 systems. The graphics drivers of all systems are up to date as well. This is really disconcerting because i want to be able to distribute this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using GLJPanel instead of GLCanvas. GLJPanel is lightweight and doesn't support more complex rendering. This was driving me crazy for the longest time.

Comment: Actually, your problem was probably caused by a feature enabled in GLJPanel by default but in general, the performance penalty compared to GLCanvas is quite small. By the way, give much more information if you want to get some help.