# JOGL takes too long to start

Tags: java, performance, startup, jogl

I'm trying to get a little bit into JOGL but it seems like I can't even get the program to start properly.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends GLJPanel implements GLEventListener {
    public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        final long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4);

        System.out.println("GLProfile#get -> " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis));
        final GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(Test.class.getName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Test t = new Test(capabilities);
        frame.add(t);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public Test(final GLCapabilities capabilities) {
        super(capabilities);

        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960, 640));
        super.addGLEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void init(final GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public final void dispose(final GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public final void display(final GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public final void reshape(final GLAutoDrawable drawable, final int x, final int y, final int width,
            final int height) {}
}
```

As you can see there isn't much going on... The code works but it takes about 15 seconds to start. I ran it using `-Xprof` which resultet in the following output:

```
Flat profile of 0.01 secs (2 total ticks): TempFileCache-Reaper

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
 50.0%     1  +     0    java.io.File.list
 50.0%     0  +     1    java.io.WinNTFileSystem.delete0
100.0%     1  +     1    Total interpreted

GLProfile#get -> 13296

Flat profile of 13.44 secs (1257 total ticks): main

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
 94.2%     0  +  1162    java.lang.ProcessImpl.create
  2.3%     0  +    28    java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load
  0.5%     6  +     0    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1
  0.2%     0  +     2    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0
  0.2%     0  +     2    sun.java2d.d3d.D3DRenderQueue.flushBuffer
  0.2%     0  +     2    java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitForInterruptibly
  0.2%     2  +     0    sun.security.provider.SHA.implCompress
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.net.NetworkInterface.getMacAddr0
  0.1%     0  +     1    sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.io.WinNTFileSystem.list
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.util.zip.ZipFile.open
  0.1%     0  +     1    jogamp.common.os.WindowsDynamicLinkerImpl.LoadLibraryW
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
  0.1%     1  +     0    jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ByteVector.<init>
  0.1%     1  +     0    java.awt.Toolkit.initAssistiveTechnologies
  0.1%     1  +     0    sun.java2d.StateTrackableDelegate.getStateTracker
  0.1%     1  +     0    gl4.helloTriangle.Test.main
  0.1%     1  +     0    jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs
  0.1%     1  +     0    java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL
  0.1%     1  +     0    com.jogamp.common.os.AndroidVersion.<clinit>
  0.1%     1  +     0    jogamp.nativewindow.jawt.JAWTUtil.getJAWT
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod0
 99.2%    17  +  1206    Total interpreted (including elided)

         Stub + native   Method                        
  0.2%     0  +     2    java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntrySize
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass
  0.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace
  0.1%     0  +     1    jogamp.common.os.WindowsDynamicLinkerImpl.LoadLibraryW
  0.5%     0  +     6    Total stub

  Thread-local ticks:
  1.9%    24             Blocked (of total)
  0.3%     4             Class loader


Flat profile of 2.08 secs (197 total ticks): D3D Screen Updater

  Thread-local ticks:
100.0%   197             Blocked (of total)


Flat profile of 2.59 secs (236 total ticks): main-SharedResourceRunner

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
 20.8%     0  +     5    jogamp.nativewindow.windows.GDI.DescribePixelFormat1
 12.5%     0  +     3    jogamp.nativewindow.windows.GDIUtil.CreateDummyDispatchThread0
  4.2%     1  +     0    com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.ProcAddressTable.isAddressField
  4.2%     1  +     0    jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLContext.getExtensionNameMap
  4.2%     0  +     1    jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WGL.dispatch_wglMakeCurrent0
  4.2%     1  +     0    sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.<init>
  4.2%     1  +     0    java.lang.Class.searchFields
  4.2%     1  +     0    sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource
  4.2%     1  +     0    jogamp.common.os.WindowsDynamicLinkerImpl.lookupSymbolLocalImpl
  4.2%     1  +     0    java.util.zip.ZipEntry.<init>
  4.2%     1  +     0    java.util.HashMap.resize
 70.8%     8  +     9    Total interpreted

     Compiled + native   Method                        
  4.2%     0  +     1    com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.opengl.GLProcAddressResolver.resolve
  4.2%     0  +     1    java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append
  4.2%     0  +     1    java.lang.reflect.Field.copy
  4.2%     0  +     1    jogamp.common.os.WindowsDynamicLinkerImpl.lookupSymbolLocalImpl
  4.2%     0  +     1    com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle.dynamicLookupFunction
  4.2%     0  +     1    com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.opengl.GLNameResolver.getFuncNamePermutation
 25.0%     0  +     6    Total compiled

         Stub + native   Method                        
  4.2%     0  +     1    jogamp.common.os.WindowsDynamicLinkerImpl.GetProcAddressA
  4.2%     0  +     1    Total stub

  Thread-local ticks:
 89.8%   212             Blocked (of total)


Flat profile of 0.01 secs (1 total ticks): NativeWindowFactory_ShutdownHook

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
100.0%     1  +     0    jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDrawableFactory.shutdownImpl
100.0%     1  +     0    Total interpreted


Flat profile of 2.98 secs (267 total ticks): AWT-Windows

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
 99.3%     0  +   265    sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop
  0.7%     0  +     2    sun.java2d.d3d.D3DGraphicsDevice.getDeviceCapsNative
100.0%     0  +   267    Total interpreted


Flat profile of 0.10 secs (10 total ticks): Thread-2

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
100.0%     0  +    10    sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.shutdown
100.0%     0  +    10    Total interpreted


Flat profile of 2.18 secs (207 total ticks): DestroyJavaVM

  Thread-local ticks:
100.0%   207             Blocked (of total)


Flat profile of 2.97 secs (267 total ticks): AWT-EventQueue-0

  Interpreted + native   Method                        
  7.1%     0  +     1    sun.awt.windows.WGlobalCursorManager.getCursorPos
  7.1%     0  +     1    sun.awt.windows.WGlobalCursorManager.findHeavyweightUnderCursor
  7.1%     0  +     1    jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.dispatch_glLinkProgram1
  7.1%     0  +     1    sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod.enableNativeIME
  7.1%     0  +     1    sun.awt.windows.WGlobalCursorManager.setCursor
  7.1%     0  +     1    jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.dispatch_glFramebufferRenderbuffer1
  7.1%     0  +     1    jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WGL.dispatch_wglMakeCurrent0
  7.1%     0  +     1    jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.dispatch_glReadPixels1
 57.1%     0  +     8    Total interpreted

         Stub + native   Method                        
  7.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.Object.hashCode
  7.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.Thread.currentThread
  7.1%     0  +     1    java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes
  7.1%     0  +     1    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry
  7.1%     0  +     1    sun.awt.windows.WGlobalCursorManager.setCursor
  7.1%     0  +     1    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1
 42.9%     0  +     6    Total stub

  Thread-local ticks:
 94.8%   253             Blocked (of total)


Flat profile of 3.07 secs (277 total ticks): AWT-Shutdown

  Thread-local ticks:
100.0%   277             Blocked (of total)


Flat profile of 3.07 secs (277 total ticks): Java2D Disposer

  Thread-local ticks:
100.0%   277             Blocked (of total)


Global summary of 15.62 seconds:
100.0%  1464             Received ticks
  2.3%    33             Compilation
  0.3%     4             Class loader
```

(Note that GLProfile#get blocks for ~13s!)

I already tested [HelloTriangle](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/helloTriangle) which leads to the same result (except for that everything is working perfectly fine, constant FPS etc.).

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Windows 10 using Nvidia GTX by the way.

Unlike [JOGL Jar runs fine on my development machine, but slowly on others? Even if they have better hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897544/jogl-jar-runs-fine-on-my-development-machine-but-slowly-on-others-even-if-they), I don't have any problems with FPS/textures, only starting the program takes too long.

Comment: Launching with the argument `-Djogamp.gluegen.UseTempJarCache=false` and using the native libraries instead of jars has done the trick for me (startup time from 15s+ to 500ms). It's not really a solution since the native libraries shouldn't be used anymore but it's still enough to debug.

Comment: @JarrodRobertson: this doesn't seem to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897544/jogl-jar-runs-fine-on-my-development-machine-but-slowly-on-others-even-if-they at all.

Comment: Which are your specs? Gpu, driver, java and jogl version

Comment: I confirm Marvin's suggestion, it's a known problem: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1301#c7 I remind that JOGL itself isn't to blame. Some virus scanners find JogAmp's automated native library extraction suspicious and take ages to scan the extracted libraries (which seems to be your problem). Sometimes, it's rather IOUtil.testDirExec() that takes a long time. Actually, the automated native library loading is a nice feature, it eases the deployment a lot but it's almost useless when you build your native bundles for a "polished" software under your control.

Comment: I just disabled Avira and now it works perfectly fine. I would never have thought of that... Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome, it confirms that Avira was to blame.